# Can't get http response as a string in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Given the source Angular Service code

```js
@Injectable()
export class HomeContentService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getContent(): Observable<string> {

    let fileURI = '/assets/content/home.md';
    let opt = { responseType: 'text' };
    return this.http.get<string>(
      fileURI,
      opt
    );

  }
```

Calling `getContent()` should return an `Observable<string>`. However, when I run `ng serve`, I get `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'json'`.

After a few tries webpack seems to compile fine without me doing any changes, but the problem happens again anytime I close the process and try to `ng serve` again.

I guess there's something wrong with my setting `responseType: 'text'`, but I don't know what it is. Googling wasn't helpful either.

Any ideas?

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(response)`

Comment: The problem happens *before* I can call anything on the result. If I `return JSON.stringify(this.http.get...)`, will the Angular component be able to subscribe to the Observable?

Comment: Also it's not a JSON string so it seems wrong to stringify it. The requested file is just Markdown text.

Answer (score 10):

You have to inline the options as this is the only way that the TypeScript transpiler can infer that you are wanting to return type `Observable<string>`.

```
getContent(): Observable<string> {
  let fileURI = '/assets/content/home.md';
  return this.http.get(fileURI, { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

See also [Http ResponseType cannot be set #18586](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586), refer to the comments made by `alxhub`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `let opt = { responseType: 'text' as 'text' };`

Explanation: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586

Answer (score 0):

i think u are not specifying map. Try this:

```
getContent ( ) : Observable< string > {
return this.http.get( YOUR REF )
       .map((res:Response) => res.text())
       .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

in res.text u specify the type, if the response was json ll be "res.Json()"

Sry for the Bad english